# Find the rate of change in a given direction of two variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, slope

The temperature of any given point on a plate is given by:
T(x,y)=180e^(−(x^2/4)−(y^2/3))
I need to find the rate of change in temperature along the direction from (2,1) to (-1,-3). I have tried taking the dot product of the gradient and unit vector, but this has not worked. I have correctly used the same technique to find the direction and magnitude of greatest increase in temperature. I have found the gradient of T to be <-180e^(-4/3), -120e^(-4/3). How do I find the rate of change from (2,1) to (-1, -3)?

Comment: It would be nice of you to show what exactly you have tried that hasn't worked, because if you did actually take the dot product of the gradient with the unit vector in the right direction, you would get the right answer. There must be some miscalculation or misunderstanding in the process of calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = (2,1), B = (-1,-3)\implies \vec{u} = \dfrac{1}{|\vec{AB}|}\vec{AB}= \left(\dfrac{-4}{5}, \dfrac{-3}{5}\right)$ is the unit vector which is also the direction in which the derivative being taken along. Thus the directional derivative you are looking for is: $\nabla_{\vec{u}} f= \nabla f\cdot \vec{u}= (f_x,f_y)\cdot \vec{u}= \dfrac{-4}{5}f_x - \dfrac{3}{5}f_y$. You can find the partial derivatives, can't you ....? Also, you need to specify the point that the directional derivative is calculated at...

Comment: Wouldn't $\vec{AB}=\langle (-1-2), (-3-1) \rangle = \langle -3, -4 \rangle$?

Comment: Directional derivatives are located at (2,1), yielding Tx = -180e^(-4/3) and Ty = -120e^(-4/3). When plugging those in to the equation multiplying gradient by unit vector, I found the answer to be 36e^(-4/3), which was incorrect.

Comment: @Julia97 $\left\langle-\frac35,-\frac45\right\rangle\cdot\langle-180,-120\rangle\ne36$.

Answer (score 0):

The directional derivative along a vector $\vec{v}$ is given by 
$$\vec{\nabla}_v f( \vec{x} ) = \vec{\nabla} f( \vec{x} ) \cdot \vec{v} $$

But since the question asks *merely in the direction of $\vec{v}$,* you must instead dot with $\hat{v}=\frac{\vec{v}}{|\vec{v}|}$.

Since you were given $f(\vec{x})=T(x,y)$ and $\vec{v}$ (found through the two points), all there's left to do is compute
$$\vec{\nabla} f( \vec{x} ) \cdot \hat{v} = \vec{\nabla} T(x,y) \cdot \hat{v} =  \left< \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial T}{\partial y} \right> \cdot \hat{v}$$

---

**Complete solution:** We have $T(x,y)=180 e^{-\frac{x^2}{4} - \frac{y^2}{3}}$ thus 
$$\vec{\nabla}T(x,y)= \left< -90 x e^{-\frac{-x^2}{4}-\frac{y^2}{3}}, -120 y e^{-\frac{x^2}{4} - \frac{y^2}{3}} \right>$$
and $\vec{v}= \left< -1-2, -3-1 \right> = \left<-3,-4 \right> \implies \hat{v}=\left< -\frac{3}{5}, -\frac{4}{5} \right>$. Thus

$$\begin{align*}
\left< \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial T}{\partial y} \right> \cdot \hat{v} &= \left< -90 x e^{-\frac{-x^2}{4}-\frac{y^2}{3}}, -120 y e^{-\frac{x^2}{4} - \frac{y^2}{3}} \right> \cdot \left< -\frac{3}{5}, -\frac{4}{5} \right> \\
&= 54 x e^{-\frac{-x^2}{4}-\frac{y^2}{3}} + 96y e^{-\frac{x^2}{4} - \frac{y^2}{3}}
\end{align*}$$